# How to remove default value of input text with new value on keyup?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input type text for input currency value. Default value of input text is 0 (zero). And I want to replace that default value when user typing the currency value and show the default value again when user clear all value.

this my code :

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon bg-custom b-0" style="font-size:1rem;">Rp.</span>
        <input type="text" name="tj_transport" value="0" onkeyup="myFunction(this)" id="testId" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This my javascript code:

```
function myFunction(e) {
    angka = e.value;
    var thisRegex = new RegExp("^(0)\d+$");
    if (thisRegex.test(angka)) {
        // remove default value / first zero value
    }
    else {
        // don't remove default value
    }
    if (angka == '') {
        e.value = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I do that ? I try to use regex but didn't work for me.. Thanks :)

Comment: You can use placeholder

Comment: Or cast with a + or parseInt/Float

Comment: Hmm.. okay, maybe I should use placeholder.. But, when input text has empty I must create default value to zero in backend for save value to databse ?

Comment: @mplungjan great idea! thanks for your answer

Comment: Also make sure to check the input on the backend. If it is not set, set to 0 there if needed

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't want to do that with javascript. Try using the html `placeholder` option instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefplaceholder

Comment: Right. I started typing before I saw his comment. Although... it feels like it should have been an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Depends on OPs usecase. For example just casting with a + will remove the 0 too

Comment: @mankowitz Hmm.. okay, maybe I should use placeholder.. But, when input text has empty I must create default value to zero in backend for save value to databse ?

Comment: @DikaAw Why? Your backend needs to check the input always anyway.

Comment: @mplungjan Right, but I think must define manually that default value to zero :D

Comment: @DikaAw you can do that at submit time